# How to call launch() twice in Java?

Tags: java, runtime-error

How to call `launch()` twice in Java?

I am given an exception like:

```
ERROR IN MAIN:java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
    Application launch must not be called more than once
```

Comment: Try to describe the problem a bit better.

Comment: At least tell us what API you're using and what class it is having the `launch()` method?!

Comment: If you show us a bit of your code, it'll go a lot simpler. Are you talking about `org.jdesktop.application.Application#launch()` method? Why do you need to call it twice?

Comment: @maksimov Aahh.. JSR-296 again.. I agree [`Application.launch(Class,String[])`](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/net/java/dev/appframework/appframework/1.03/appframework-1.03-javadoc.jar!/org/jdesktop/application/Application.html#launch%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String[]%29) is a good possibility here.

Answer (score 3):

Based on googling the the error message string and reading some of the search results, I believe that you must be using one of the

```
    javafx.application.Application.launch(...)
```

methods.  The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/Application.html#launch%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String...%29) for the methods says this:

> *"Launch a standalone application. This method is typically called from the main method(). **It must not be called more than once or an exception will be thrown.**"*

So if my guess is right about with "launch" you are using, the answer is: You can't call `launch` twice.

---

<sub>(I was going to read the source code to see if I could figure out why this restriction exists, but my normal approach to finding the code failed.  Does anyone know why "the usual places" don't appear to have indexed the source code for JavaFX?)</sub>

---

If you provided more information, we might be able to suggest an alternative approach.

Comment: [Partial JavaFX source](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/rt/file/tip) is available today as part of the [open-jfx project](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/openjfx/).  The [Application](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/rt/file/tip/javafx-ui-common/src/javafx/application/Application.java) class calls an internal [LauncherImpl](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/rt/file/tip/javafx-ui-common/src/com/sun/javafx/application/LauncherImpl.java) class which confirms your guess.

Answer (score 0):

It really shouldn't be called twice, because it mostly initialize application components, not only your very classes. You should rather consider adding some state object in a launch method and a callback that would 'launch' your function several times.

`Launch` method counts how many times it's been called because it is really dangerous for an application to call it more times. If someone from above decided to put a mechanism preventing such an action, why would you want to breach through it.